# Using String as JSON key for Firebase update()

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The following JavaScript updates my firebase:

```
db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update({
                         img1: pic
                      });
```

I have img1, img2, img3 in my database. I want to use a for loop to update the values like so:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  let s = "img" + i;

  db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update({
                         s: pic
                      });
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, change the code like this:

```
db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update({
    [s]: pic
});
```

This way, you'll use the value of s as the name of the field to update.